# ADSL modem to Wireless AP

Tags: adsl

I had MTNL. Before that I used adsl2 modem to give me internet access.
Now I switched over to a local ISP so wanted to convert the ADSL modem to Wireless AP. The problem is that even after disabling NAT and DHCP, I am unable to access internet over wireless, but I can access internet over wired interface via LAN. Can u please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is DHCP related; you have to fix a static IP address for your WiFi card, Example: your router address is

> 192.168.1.1

you have to choose

> 192.168.1.xxx

if this address it is not used by other devices.